# Weak convergence in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and convergence of integrals: an analysis of common statements

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, variational-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, with $N>2$, be a bounded domain and let $2^*$ be the critical Sobolev exponent given by
$$2^* := \dfrac{2N}{N-2}.$$
If $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, we can guarantee the existence of a subsequence $(u_{n_j})$ such that $u_{n_j} \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Under these conditions, we cannot affirm that
$$\int_{\Omega} |u_{n_j}|^{2^* - 2}u_{n_j}v \to \int_{\Omega} |u|^{2^* - 2}uv$$
for every $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Comment: What is the $2^*$ in the exponent?

Comment: $2^*$ is the critical Sobolev exponent.

Comment: Here is a comment which may be of help or not : you're basically asking whether $|u_{n_j}|^{2^* - 2}u_{n_j}\rightharpoonup|u|^{2^* - 2}u$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ whenever $u_{n_j} \rightharpoonup u$. I think the way to go about it would be to first prove that $|u_{n_j}|^{2^* - 2}\rightharpoonup|u|^{2^* - 2}$, and then that a [product of weakly convergent subsequences is weakly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629822/convergence-of-product-of-weakly-converging-sequences-in-lp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$ with $p = \frac{N+2}{N-2}=2^*-1$ (which is smaller than the critical exponent).

If $v\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ then
$$
\int_\Omega |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n \cdot v \to 
\int_\Omega |u|^{2^*-2}u \cdot v
$$
due to the strong convergence of $u_n$ in $L^p$.

Now take $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $w\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$.
Then
$$
\int_\Omega( |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n- |u|^{2^*-2}u) \cdot v
=\int_\Omega( |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n- |u|^{2^*-2}u) \cdot (v-w)
+\int_\Omega( |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n- |u|^{2^*-2}u) \cdot w.
$$
Due to density,
we can choose $w$ such that the first integral is smaller than some $\epsilon>0$:
$$
\left| \int_\Omega( |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n- |u|^{2^*-2}u) \cdot (v-w) \right|
\le 2^p ( \|u_n\|_{L^p}^p + \|u\|_{L^p}^p) \|v-w\|_{L^p} 
\le c ( \|u_n\|_{L^p}^p + \|u\|_{L^p}^p) \|v-w\|_{H^1} \le \epsilon.
$$
With $w$ fixed, we can pass to the limit in the second integral to obtain
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_\Omega( |u_n|^{2^*-2}u_n- |u|^{2^*-2}u) \cdot v \right|\le \epsilon.
$$